# Solving a piecewise ODE initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

***Find all solutions to the following initial value problem, or show that no solution exists:***

$\begin{align}
y^{\prime}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
3 x^2-1 & \text { if } x<-1 \\
0 & \text { if } x \geq-1
\end{array} \quad \text { with } y(-2)=1\right.
\end{align}$

---

How do I even begin to solve this problem? Our textbook also gives this theorem, which I tried applying (not sure if it can actually be applied here) to show that a solution does not exist:

**

---

***Theorem 1.4.4: Existence***

If $F(x,y)$ is continuous for all $(x,y)$ near $(x_0, y_0)$, then the initial value problem
$$y’=F(x,y), \quad (x_0)=y_0$$
Has a solution $y=y(x)$ for $x$ near $x_0$

---

but since this is only an introductory calculus course, we do not really prove the theorem, nor do we work with a rigid notion of "nearness". I tried graphing $y'$ and applying the theorem to show that $y'$ is discontinuous at $x=-1$, but did not really know "how near" would be "near enough" for "$x$ near $x_0$".

Comment: Depends what you mean by solution. It won't have a solution which is differentiable everywhere. Can you solve it in $-2\le x <-1$? Can you solve it for $x \ge -1$?

Comment: I think you're asking the right questions, Jason.  By that I mean you're considering the consequence of the theorem before simply plunging into symbol manipulation to solve the ODE.  Since the initial condition, which is needed for an exact solution, is provided at x = -2, I believe the neighborhood about this point is the one you should consider.  In this case, a suitable neighborhood would be all x < -1.  Solve it in that neighborhood and treat x > -1 separately and try to piece them together for a continuous solution.

Answer (score 1):

Direct integration of the ODE yields
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3-x+c_1&\text{if $x<-1$,} \\
c_2&\text{if $x\geq-1$.}
\end{cases} \tag{1}
$$
The initial condition $y(-2)=1$ implies $(-2)^3-(-2)+c_1=1$, or $c_1=7$. To determine $c_2$, we impose continuity of $y(x)$ at $x=-1$:
$$
\lim_{x\to-1^{-}}y(x)=\lim_{x\to-1^{+}}y(x)\implies c_1=c_2 \implies c_2=7. \tag{2}
$$
In conclusion,
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3-x+7&\text{if $x<-1$,} \\
7&\text{if $x\geq-1$.}
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$$

Comment: How do you know that y(x) is continuous at x=-1?

Comment: I could imagine a none piecewise linear taxation function (with x being gross pay and y being net pay) that would not be continuous I.e contains poverty traps at taxation band boundaries.

Comment: @JasonXu, the integral of a piecewise continuous function is continuous.

Comment: But wouldn't y(x) be non-differentiable at $x=-2$?: 

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{y(-2+h)-y(-2)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{(-2+h)^3-(-2+h)+8}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\left[h^2-6h+11+2/h \right ]=0-0+11-\infty=-\infty$$.

Thus y(x) is overall non-differentiable cannot work as a solution.

Comment: y(x) Also seems to be non-differentiable at x=-1

Comment: Redo your calculation of $y'(-2)$: if $x<-1$, $y(x)=x^3-x+7$, therefore $y'(x)=3x^2-1$; in particular, $y'(-2)=11$.

Comment: Regarding the non-differentiability of $y(x)$ at $x=-1$, you are correct. However, since the discontinuity of $y'(x)$ is finite at $x=-1$ $(y'(-1^+)-y'(-1^-)=-2)$,  $y(x)=1+\int_{-2}^{x} y'(x')\,dx'$ exists and is continuous at $x=-1$.